General form of the integral: $\int_0^b \frac{\left(1+\frac{x-a}{| x-a| }\right) (x-a)^n}{\sqrt{x | x-a| }} \, dx$ for integer $n$
Though this might be challenging to solve, I thought I'd ask here for your insights.
Could someone suggest a general form or a recursive formula for this integral for integer $n$ and $n >= 0$?
$$\int_0^b \frac{\left(1+\frac{x-a}{| x-a| }\right) (x-a)^n}{\sqrt{x | x-a| }} \, dx$$
Assume: $a > 0, b > a$
I was able to find for discrete values of $n$, but could not come up with a general formula:
$n=0: -2 \left(\log (a)-2 \log \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}\right)-\log (b)\right)$
$n=1: 2 \left(\sqrt{b (-a+b)}-a \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}\right)\right)$
$n=2: \frac{1}{4} \left(-10 a \sqrt{-((a-b) b)}+4 \sqrt{-\left((a-b) b^3\right)}-3 a^2 \log (a)+6 a^2 \log
   \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}\right)+3 a^2 \log (b)\right)$
$n=3: \frac{1}{24} \left(66 a^2 \sqrt{-((a-b) b)}-52 a \sqrt{-\left((a-b) b^3\right)}+16 \sqrt{-\left((a-b) b^5\right)}+15
   a^3 \log (a)-30 a^3 \log \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}\right)-15 a^3 \log (b)\right)$
$n=4: \frac{1}{192} \left(-558 a^3 \sqrt{-((a-b) b)}+652 a^2 \sqrt{-\left((a-b) b^3\right)}-400 a \sqrt{-\left((a-b)
   b^5\right)}+96 \sqrt{-\left((a-b) b^7\right)}-105 a^4 \log (a)+210 a^4 \log \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}}\right)+105
   a^4 \log (b)\right)$

How did you come up with your answers  so far? The integral is really only between $a$ and $b$. Did you use a recurrence relation ?

First of all, $\frac{x - a}{|x - a|} = 1$ if $x > a$, $-1$ else so your integral vanishes when $0 < x < a$. If we call it $I_n$, we have,
$$
I_n = \int_a^b \frac{2(x - a)^n}{\sqrt{x(x - a)}} \, dx = 2\int_0^{b - a} x^{n - 1/2}(x + a)^{-1/2} \, dx.
$$
Then, with an integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
I_{n + 1} & = 2\int_0^{b - a} x^{n + 1/2}(x + a)^{-1/2} \, dx\\
& = 2[x^{n + 1/2}\frac{(x + a)^{1/2}}{1/2}]_0^{b - a} - 2\int_0^{b - a} (n + 1/2)x^{n - 1/2}\frac{(x + a)^{1/2}}{1/2} \, dx\\
& = 4(b - a)^{n + 1/2}\sqrt{b} - 2(2n + 1)\int_0^{b - a} x^{n - 1/2}(x + a)(x + a)^{-1/2} \, dx\\
& = 4(b - a)^{n + 1/2}\sqrt{b} - 2(2n + 1)\int_0^{b - a} x^{n + 1/2}(x + a)^{-1/2} \, dx\\
& \ \ \ \ - 2a(2n + 1)\int_0^{b - a} x^{n - 1/2}(x + a)^{-1/2} \, dx\\
& = 4(b - a)^{n + 1/2}\sqrt{b} - (2n + 1)I_{n + 1} - a(2n + 1)I_n.
\end{align*}
You deduce that,
$$
I_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2n + 2}\left(4(b - a)^{n + 1/2}\sqrt{b} - a(2n + 1)I_n\right).
$$

Thank you so much
